# testing symfony API in gitlab pipelines - SimpleXMLElement not allowed

Tags: symfony, phpunit, gitlab-ci

I try to write tests for my symfony API (symfony version : 3.4).

My symfony project is made to be the API.

When i run my test with this command on my computer or in the docker image pushed in my test environment, it works :

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

When i try to launch it in in gitlab pipelines, it fails.
Extract from .gitlab-ci.yml

```
phpcs:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - main
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_BRANCH
    - docker run  $REGISTRY_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_BRANCH ./vendor/bin/phpcs --error-severity=1 --warning-severity=8 --extensions=php
```

Error in gitlab :

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\AppBundle\Controller\ItemControllerTest::testPostItem
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: {"code":500,"message":"Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed"}

/var/www/html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/ItemControllerTest.php:32

Caused by
ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 75 bytes in /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php:271
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess::PHPUnit\Util\PHP\{closure}(8, 'unserialize(): ...', '/var/www/html/v...', 271, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php(271): unserialize('{"code":500,"me...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php(170): PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess->processChildResult(Object(Tests\AppBundle\Controller\ItemControllerTest), Object(    PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult), '{"code":500,"me...', '')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(676): PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess->runTestJob('<?php declare(s...', Object(Tests\AppBundle\Controller\ItemControllerTest), Object(    PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#4 /var/www/html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/ItemControllerTest.php(32): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(568): Tests\AppBundle\Controller\ItemControllerTest->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(568): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(616): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(201): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite), Array, true)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(160): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(61): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#11 {main}
```

Extract of my ItemControlleTest :

```
$postData = array
    (
        'name' => 'test,
    );
$this->client->request(Request::METHOD_POST, $this->appUrl.'/api/item', $postData);
$this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

thanks

Comment: It looks like a `phpunit` error, not a `phpcs` error. My guess is that the phpunit configuration used on gitlab is converting some php errors to exceptions (ErrorException). For example take a look at PHPUnit configurations like  `convertNoticesToExceptions`: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/configuration.html. And look for differences in the gitlab configs and your test system.

Comment: thanks. I had made a copy / paste mistake, it was effectively "phpunit". I will look into if i can find something